# Unicode string matching

Tags: java, string, unicode, string-matching

I want to match two strings with Unicode encoding in Java. I want to match something like:

```
"asdfeo"
"ásdfeó"
```

How can I return 0 in the `compareTo()` method?

---

**EDIT:**

When I type a string into an autocomplete view without diacritics (for some reason I don't have the keyboard to write those diacritics), I want to see between the autocomplete suggestions the objects with diacritics. That is why I want to overwrite the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: @bicska88: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: What Aaron is asking is *the most important question* here. There are several ways to (kind-of) do what you ask and which one to choose depends on what *exactly* you try to achieve with this. The diacritics are not just "funny things that hang on characters", they actually *matter* in most languages where they are used. Sometimes *a lot*. Removing/ignoring them is *usually* not the best choice.

Comment: @JoachimSauer there you have the motivation, Mister.

Comment: @bicska88: that's a good reason. Don't get me wrong: I don't try to "police" this issue, it's just that different motivations might require different solutions (and some might even require an entirely different approach).

Comment: @JoachimSauer exactly. Please don't get me wrong either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) API.

Comment: Particularly a `Collator` with strength `PRIMARY`.